# Scroll bar not appearing in QScrollArea (PyQt6) when using GraphicsLayoutWiget (pyqtgraph)

Tags: pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I am trying to get the scroll bar to appear using a QScrollArea in PyQt6 with an embedded GraphicsLayoutWidget in pyqtgraph.

I have tried modifying the layout, reassigning the GraphicsLayoutWidget, setting a default minimum size for the GraphicsLayoutWidget, and calling the show() function.

Here is the code of the problem section. Where I create a series of graphs and place them into the GraphicsLayout widget using the addPlot function.

```
    def update_graphs(self):
        self.graphWidget.clear()
        self.graph_data = pd.concat([self.data[(self.data['time'] > (comment - self.time_before)) & (self.data['time'] < (comment + self.time_after))] for comment in self.selected_comments['time']])
        self.graph_dict = dict.fromkeys(self.graph_data.columns.values[:-1], None)
        time = (self.graph_data['time'].dt.tz_localize(None) - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01") + pd.Timedelta('5h')) / pd.Timedelta('1s')
        for i, trace in enumerate(self.graph_dict.keys()):
            self.graph_dict[trace] = self.graphWidget.addPlot(row=i,
                                                              col=0,
                                                              name=trace,
                                                              title=trace
                                                              )
            self.graph_dict[trace].setMinimumHeight(150)
            self.graph_dict[trace].addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(clear=True,
                                                            pen='g',
                                                            x=time.values,
                                                            y=self.graph_data[trace].values),
                                           row=i,
                                           col=0)
            self.graph_dict[trace].setXLink(list(self.graph_dict.keys())[0])
            y_axis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='left', text='Voltage', units='V', unitPrefix='m')
            y_axis.setLabel(text='Voltage', units='V')
            y_axis.setScale(1e-3)
            self.graph_dict[trace].setAxisItems({'bottom': pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom'),
                                                 'left': y_axis})
            if not i == len(self.graph_dict) - 1:
                self.graph_dict[trace].hideAxis('bottom')
        self.scrollArea.show()
```

The Qt designer file generate this code for the relevant section.

```
self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(parent=self.graphTab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.SizeAdjustPolicy.AdjustIgnored)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.graphWidget = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.graphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1043, 655))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.graphWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.graphWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.graphWidget.setObjectName("graphWidget")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.graphWidget)
```

[What this code generates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbJes.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what feels like a hack to force the QScrollArea to figure out that the GraphicsLayoutWidget is bigger than the window.

You need to resize the Widget manually. So at some point either before or after the graphs are generated you can set the minimum size of the Widget to be the size you expect:
`self.graphWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0,len(self.graph_dict) * 150))`